# Saving Thales keys to different location than KMDATA/local

Tags: hsm

I'm generating cryptographic keys using Thales HSMs. The encrypted keys are stored to /opt/nfast/kmdata/local. Since I may need to generate a very important number of keys (over 20 000 keys), I thought storing all the keys to a single directory won't be the best option (I'm mainly afraid of performance issues).

I would like to either split the local directory to sub directories or ideally store the keys to a RDBMS database.

Is there any "standard" way to update the default HSM behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Ask Thales support about it (my bet is that it is not possible to change).

There are some ideas how you might deal with this situation:

**1. OS level**

- use OS and filesystem suitable for storing that many files in a single directory

**2. Application level**

- use key diversification instead of key generation (if possible for your use case) -- i.e. if you need to provide keys for thousands of entities use a master key and diversify all keys for your entities using this master key and some diversification data (e.g. entity identity / serial number / etc.). This way you don't need to store thousands of keys as you simply diversify them on-demand. Remember to carefully analyze if you can use key diversification at all (as there are some consequences)
- store those keys encrypted outside the security world (if possible for your use case) -- i.e. import/generate each key as temporal object and immediately wrap it using some persistent wrapping key (you could call this key LMK). Safely store the wrapped value in RDBMS (or anywhere else) and delete the temporal object. Later when you need to access this particular key you simply unwrap it back into temporal object and use it. Again this approach has some consequences and you must analyze thoroughly if it can be used in your situation

Good luck with your project!

Disclaimer: I am no crypto expert so please do validate my thoughts.

Comment: Actually an HSM (at least a Thales/nCipher one) will always export the generated keys and softcards automatically. They are saved to the local directory after being protected by the HSM master key. You cannot simply use this data without using the HSM master key (the same HSM or another HSM having the same security wold (ACS)
I'm actually using the default HSM configuration which stores all the data to a unique directory called "local". I prefer to use a database to store the data because I'm expecting the number of keys/softcards to be around 100 000.

Comment: @ferjani I know that. I meant that you can use the same technique on top of any PKCS#11 device supporting wrap/unwrap...